# Email treated as SPAM when has Links

Tags: php, email, outlook, spam, hotmail

I've work all day long on that crazy problem.

I created an HTML email that will be sent massively.
I Use *PHPMailer* and I tried *Mail* Function. Both *PHPMailer*, it's *SMTP* feature and the *native Mail* Function works well.

**GOOD - PASS THE SPAM FILTER**

The problem is when I put a link in the HTML code, the email turns into SPAM.
But not any links. If I put a link that the href is "http://www.google.com" then It passes the filter. Samething on my company domain name "http://www.sequencedigitale.com", it passes the filter as well.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">This is Google Website</a>
```

**WRONG - DON'T PASS THE SPAM FILTER**

What turns me crazy is when I put the same domain name as the server that process the email submission. I have 3 domains names that point on that server, every of those 3 don't pass the filter.

```
<a href="http://careers.fieracapital.com">This doesn't pass the filter</a>
```

I checked on some Blacklist checkers and the IP isn't block on 100% of the lists.

The IP is **184.107.100.61**

The problem happened to me on *Hotmail*, *Outlook* and on a Server runned with *Plesk*.
It passes the filter on *GMail*.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Carl.

Comment: How is your domain name being in spam filters a programming problem?

Comment: which spam identification software ?

Comment: If I put a link with href="http://google.com" is goes in the Inbox folder. If I put a link with href="http://careers.fieracapital.com", same domain as my PHP script located, it goes in the Junk Mail. That is the only issue. There is nothing else that is responsible of this reaction.

Comment: @dragon, I test my IP on blacklist checker such as "list-checker.online-domain-tools.com"

Comment: no i mean what filter is marking your email as spam?

Answer (score 1):

> email that will be sent massively.

That's sort of what spam is, but you can try to make it less spammy so it passes through more filters.

It's good to make the From address be one that's from the SMTP server (use Reply-To if you want replies).  If you can get an email server that's already reputable, that will get you closer to your goal.

It's mostly dependent on the proprietary filters Microsoft is using, so there's not a whole lot that can be done.

Comment: Hi! I put Both From and Reply-To and use the SMTP feature to make sure it passes this kind of filter. Still in the Junk Mail but only when I use the domain name in a link. Really weird.